Why is the character set for the uca1400_ai_ci collation NULL?
I've been working with database collations of late. I generally don't like ambiguous queries such as SHOW COLLATION so I eventually found the source via the following query:
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS 
ORDER BY CHARACTER_SET_NAME ASC, COLLATION_NAME ASC;

I now have the option to update the collation to uca1400_ai_ci however the associated character set value is NULL.
Why is the uca1400_ai_ci NULL and what, if any considerations should I have while updating from the character set utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci?

What version of MariaDB?

@RickJames 10.11 and I posted a bug report here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-34631 though I think the person who responded is being lazy.

There are many character sets that correspond to the uca1400_ai_ci collation.
Per the response in JIRA MDEV-34631 the character sets that can be used with uca1400_ai_ci can be seen by COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY:
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT *  FROM information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY  WHERE COLLATION_NAME='uca1400_
+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+------------+
| COLLATION_NAME | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | FULL_COLLATION_NAME   | ID   | IS_DEFAULT |
+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+------------+
| uca1400_ai_ci  | ucs2               | ucs2_uca1400_ai_ci    | 2560 |            |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf16              | utf16_uca1400_ai_ci   | 2816 |            |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf32              | utf32_uca1400_ai_ci   | 3072 |            |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf8mb3            | utf8mb3_uca1400_ai_ci | 2048 |            |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf8mb4            | utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci | 2304 |            |
+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+------------+

As a backwards compatibility option, old_mode=no_null_collation_ids was created to get the character sets out of information_schema.COLLATIONS:
MariaDB [(none)]> set old_mode=no_null_collation_ids;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT *  FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS  WHERE COLLATION_NAME='uca1400_ai_ci' ORDER BY CHARACTER_SET_NAME ASC;
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| COLLATION_NAME | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID   | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| uca1400_ai_ci  | ucs2               | 2560 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf16              | 2816 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf32              | 3072 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf8mb3            | 2048 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_ai_ci  | utf8mb4            | 2304 |            | Yes         |       8 |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+

